# How to read XML data

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have XML string which I am trying to read with code

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(XMLString);
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//cart/cart-item/url/text()");
Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
```

But `node` is always null. Could anyone explain what is wrong?

```
<order xmlns="http://ws.plimus.com">
<order-id>8301446</order-id>
<ordering-shopper>
<shopper-id>25879327</shopper-id>
</ordering-shopper>
<cart>
<charged-currency>USD</charged-currency>
<cart-item>
<sku>...</sku>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<url>
https://ws.plimus.com:443/services/2/subscriptions/9433117
</url>
<item-sub-total>9.00</item-sub-total>
</cart-item>
<tax>0.00</tax>
<tax-rate>0</tax-rate>
<total-cart-cost>9.00</total-cart-cost>
</cart>
</order>
```

Comment: what is "//cart/cart-item/url/text()" ?

Comment: The path to the Url value. I need to read https://ws.plimus.com:443/services/2/subscriptions/9433117

Comment: Can't open your url, its asking me username/password.

Comment: Jitendra, it is his url in the xml :)

Comment: XmlNodeList abc = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("url"); string value = abc.Item(0).InnerText;   This shall also work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default XPath considers unprefixed names to be in "no namespace". You should use `XmlNamespaceManager` to resolve xmlns

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNamespaceManager nm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);

nm.AddNamespace("ns", "http://ws.plimus.com");
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:cart/ns:cart-item/ns:url/text()", nm);

Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
```

Edit:
If you have the possibility to change xml root element to

`<order xmlns:ns="http://ws.plimus.com">`

then you don't need to specify 'ns' in XPath every time, it would look like `//cart/cart-item/url/text()`.

`XmlNamespaceManager` configuration as shown in example is required anyway

Comment: Note: if you have the possibility to change xml namespace declaration to xmlns:ns="...", then you can omit 'ns:' clause in XPath

Comment: you can also use XmlNodeList abc = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("url"); string value = abc.Item(0).InnerText;

Comment: Yes, I just didn't want to change XPath, because it is already used in current solution

Answer (score -1):

When you specify // in xpath it determines starting from root element, so your xpath should be:

`XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//order/cart/cart-item/url/text()");`